# Matrix with Complex Entries

Tags: matrices

> Let $A, B \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ be such that matrix $I_n - AB$ is non-singular and $$A^2B^2 = A^2 + B^2 - AB = I_n$$ Then, it is necessary that
>
> 1. $(A-B)^2 = 2 I_n$
> 2. $(A + B) (A - B) = 2 A^2$
> 3. $A^4 =-I_n$
> 4. $\det A$ is unimodular

---

This is a multiple choice question with more than one entries correct.

My approach is as follow

${A^2}{B^2} = {A^2} + {B^2} - AB = {I_n}$

$T = {A^2}{B^2} = {A^2} + {B^2} - AB = {I_n}$

$\det T = {\left( {\det A} \right)^2}{\left( {\det B} \right)^2} = 1$

$\left( {\det A} \right)\left( {\det B} \right) =  \pm 1$

How do I proceed from here

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by $\det A$ is unimodular? Is it that $\lvert \det A \rvert = 1$ or that $\det A = \pm 1$?

Comment: a unimodular matrix M is a square integer matrix having determinant +1 or −1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying $A^2 + B^2 - AB = I$ on the right by $B^2$ gives

$$\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\underbrace{\color{black}{A^2 B^2}}_{=I}} + B^4 - AB^3 &= B^2 \\
I - B^2 + B^4 &= AB^3 \\
\color{blue}{\bigl(}I - B^2 + B^4\color{blue}{\bigr) \cdot B^{-3}} &= AB^3 \color{blue}{\cdot B^{-3}}  \\
B^{-3} - B^{-1} + B &= A.
\end{align}
$$

Since $A$ is a sum of powers of $B$, it follows that $A$ and $B$ commute. Then $$(I - AB) (I + AB) = I - A^2 B^2 = O$$ together with $I - AB$ being invertible implies that $AB = -I$. Hence $$A^2 + B^2 = I + AB = O.$$

Thus

1. $(A - B)^2 = A^2 - 2 AB + B^2 = I - AB = 2I$;
2. $(A - B) (A + B) = A^2 - B^2 = 2 A^2$;
3. Multiply $A^2 B^2 = A^2 + B^2 - AB$ by $A^2$ to get

$$\begin{align}
A^4 B^2 &= A^4 + \color{blue}{\underbrace{\color{black}{A^2 B^2}}_{=I}} - A^3 B \\
A^4 B^2 + A^3 B &= A^4 + I \\
\bigl(A^3 B\bigr) \color{blue}{\underbrace{\color{black}{\bigl(AB + I\bigr)}}_{=O}} &= A^4 + I \\
A^4 &= -I; \text{and}
\end{align}
$$

4. If a unimodular determinant is meant to be one whose modulus $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ is $1$, then this immediately follows from $\det A^4 = (-1)^n \implies \lvert \det A \rvert = 1$.

---

*Note*: The entries do not have to be integers, nor does the determinant of $A$ have to be $\pm 1$ as seen by

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 + i) & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 + i)
\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } B = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1 + i) & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1 + i)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which satisfy all the conditions in the problem. Here $\det A = i$.

Comment: Can you explain me this line "Since A is the sum of the power of B it follows that A and B commute

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi sure. Every matrix commutes with powers of itself, i.e., $B B^n = B^{n+1} = B^n B$. Applying that to $A = B^{-3} - B^{-1} + B$, gives $$\begin{align}A B &=  \bigl(B^{-3} - B^{-1} + B\bigr) B \\ &= B^{-2} - B^0 + B^2 \\ &= B\bigl(B^{-3} - B^{-1} + B\bigr) \\ &= B A. \end{align}$$ So $A B = B A$. In other words, $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: Thankyou for your prompt reply